# Warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, parsing, promise

When I open my freshly build app for the first time, the following warning appears. I think it's because the key in `AsyncStorage.getItem("KEY")` doesn't have any value when app runs for the very first time. How do I handle this promise rejection?

[image: warning output]

```
this.state = {
      subjects: [],
      text: "",
      present_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      total_count: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      present: 0,
      total: 0
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    Subjects.all(subjects => this.setState({ subjects: subjects || [] }));
    AsyncStorage.getItem("PRESENT_COUNT").then((value) => {
      this.setState({ present_count: JSON.parse(value || this.state.present_count) });
    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem("TOTAL_COUNT").then((value) => {
      this.setState({ total_count: JSON.parse(value || this.state.total_count) });
    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem("PRESENT").then((value) => {
      this.setState({ present: JSON.parse(value || this.state.present) });
    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem("TOTAL").then((value) => {
      this.setState({ total: JSON.parse(value || this.state.total) });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if block inside .then

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("KEY").then((value) => {
          if(value){
          this.setState({ present_count: JSON.parse(value || this.state.present_count) });
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `AsyncStorage.getItem` is an asynchronous operation. In that case, it will be necessary to `await` for the `getItem` operations to be completed. You can make use of Promise.all to wait for the getItem methods to be completed before updating the state.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const getPresentCount = AsyncStorage.getItem('PRESENT_COUNT');
  const getTotalCount = AsyncStorage.getItem('TOTAL_COUNT');
  const getPresent = AsyncStorage.getItem('PRESENT');
  const getTotal = AsyncStorage.getItem('TOTAL');

  const [presentCount, totalCount, present, total] = await Promise.all([getPresentCount, getTotalCount, getPresent, getTotal]);
  this.setState({
    present_count: JSON.parse(value) || this.state.present_count,
    total_count: JSON.parse(value) || this.state.total_count,
    present: JSON.parse(value) || this.state.present,
    total: JSON.parse(value) || this.state.total,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**One way is to check if `value` is all good.**

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem("PRESENT_COUNT")
  .then((value) => {
    this.setState({
      present_count: value ? JSON.parse(value) : this.state.present_count
    });
  })
```

**Another way is to use catch block**

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem("PRESENT_COUNT")
  .then((value) => {
    this.setState({
      present_count: JSON.parse(value || this.state.present_count),
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.setState({ someState: "someVal" }); // if required...
  });
```

**Finally** you can also consider to use promise.all as mentioned in another answer (by @wentjun). Just note that if any one of your api call is failed, you will end up in not setting any state. Also make sure to use try catch when using async/await.